# Migrate Google Apps data to another Google Apps account

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, migrate-data

So, I have a domain `example.com` which is using Google Apps for Business account through a user `x@xyz.com`.

I want to transfer (or migrate) all the complete ownership of my email, contacts, etc. belonging to `example.com` to another Google Apps for Business Account with a user `y@abc.com`.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What about setting up an alias? Or how about some of these? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps%5D+transfer+is%3Aq

Answer (score 2):

Instead of transferring ownership of your Google Apps data, a process which is not provided by Google with a "right-click" simplicity, you can migrate all of your Google Apps Account data to another Google Apps Account.

The result will be equal of what you are trying to do.

This article in [Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en) gives explanation for migrating data between Google Apps account (Contacts, Calendars, Drive files, Sites, Other Google Apps)

### Migrate Emails between Google Apps accounts

> The [data migration service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6167866) is the recommended way to migrate mail.
>   It's clientless and cloud-based and easy to set up and monitor. You do
>   everything in the Google Admin console.
>
> Google Apps [Migration for Microsoft® Exchange](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6270754) (GAMME) is a utility
>   that migrates your mail, including labels and archived mail, to
>   another account. GAMME can also migrate other data, but requires you
>   to install the tool first.
>
> [..]

### Migrate Contacts

> You can [export Gmail contacts to a CSV file](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911) and then use that file to
>   migrate your contacts.

### Migrate Calendars

> [..] You can also download all the calendars in your My calendars list or you can choose to share individual calendars
>   with email addresses in your new account. See [Export your
>   calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?) for details.

### Migrate Drive Files

> [...] you can use the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) to export and import documents.

### Migrate Sites

> You can share individual sites with an email address on your new domain and then [transfer the website to Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48313).

### Migrate other Google Apps

> There are options for migrating data from other Google Apps products. See [Moving product](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) data for details.

Comment: Answer updated !